# Looking for a word that means an implicit assumption

Tags: vocabulary

For example, if one believes that A is true, whereas A is true because of some unspoken assumption B. 
Is there a word to describe such B?

Answer (score 3):

You already used one such name, *implicit*, when you called it *implicit assumption*. Another word that is used is *tacit*, as in *tacit assumption*.

You can also say that B is a *premise* for A. Although the word *premise* doesn't imply the meaning of being *unspoken*. That would need to be added by another word, like *implicit premise*.

Answer (score 1):

You might find some of the language you need in this description of the [Gettier Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettier_problem) on the Wikipedia.

In 1963, Edmund Gettier published a short paper in *Analysis*, questioning the conventional wisdom that knowledge could be defined as “justified true belief”. There are now a vast number of “Gettier type counterexamples”, some of which might align with what you are looking for.

The question you are asking is actually quite deep. There are quite a few words that could be used to describe your hypothetical assumption B. In the Responses to Gettier section of the Wikipedia article, you’ll see that many noted philosophers have tackled the problem in their own way.

For a single word, though, [putative](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/putative) might be a reasonable choice.

Answer (score 0):

> Looking for a word that means an implicit assumption?

**ostensible** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ostensible)

> 1. apparent; seeming

A is **ostensibly** true, an unspoken assumption.

B = **ostensibility**

As in:

> It also potentially tees up a Supreme Court battle that will test the
>   conservative majority’s ostensible commitment to religious freedom.
>   Slate Feb 5, 2019